# Angular 5 - How to fetch data using curl and display it?

Tags: angular5

Hey Guys I'm new to Angular, can somebody help me how to fetch the data and display it in a component with the following details, just a format will help me.

> curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization:
>   Token a41d2b39e3b47412504509bb5a1b66498fb1f43a" -H "Cache-Control:
>   no-cache" "https://api.mywebsite.co.in/v1/mf/?key=118656INF204K01E05"

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you want get the full response from the api you need to use HttpClient module.

getting full response from api Working example Check this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-64qrhq?file=app%2Fdata.service.ts

Comment: Thanks Chellapan, I tried using your code, but im getting this error in console "server responded with a status of 401 (UNAUTHORIZED)". Can you please help me add the authorization details? Thank you.

Comment: can you able to see the response on browser by using url?

Comment: This is what I'm seeing when opening the url in browser:

HTTP 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
Allow: OPTIONS, GET

{
    "status-message": "User Unauthorized",
    "data": {},
    "status-code": -1
}

Comment: You need authentication to access that url

Comment: I have an access token, will that be enough? Also not sure how to apply the access token, can you please help me?